# Application Server equivalent on Windows

Tags: c#, .net

I have a question regarding how to write a windows server side application.

We have now have a system whose client is .NET 4.0 based and a server side application running on jboss on Linux. The server application talks to an Oracle DB.

I am now thinking to move the server side to Windows and DB to SQL server. The server application should be written in C# on .NET as well. However, there seems no Application Server equivalent on Windows. How is a server application normally written and deployed on Windows?

Many thanks

Comment: Kevin, can you provide some details about the functionality you expect from an application server? There are a number of alternatives in the .NET world, but it depends on what you want to do.

Comment: I simply need the service to listen to a number of clients application's call (max 10). They will send some trade information to the server and the service log them in to database. The clients are desktop application and not web application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few options, but the very basics would be

1. Host WCF web services in IIS and take advantage of the management IIS offers, you can bring [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) into the picture for more robust and manageable hosting.
2. Self host your service in a Windows Service.

If it suites your application I would say the [AppFabric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849) solution is worth looking at. But this is not a 1-to-1 with with a Java Application Server.

---

**Update**

Self hosting WCF is as simple as the follow

```
host = new ServiceHost(typeof(YourWcfService));
host.Open();
```

This assumes that you have defined a service called `YourWcfService'. The above code in the`OnStart` of a Windows Service will start accepting requests to your service. Of course this still requires all the basic configuration in the app.config file.

AppFabric, however gives you a nice environment to manage and monitor your services, so not to sound like a broken record, but I would look into it to see if it is possibly a good fit for you.

---

**Update 2:**

I did a quick `bing` and found this MSDN post, it is oldish but looks like a good example.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332338.aspx

Comment: My client application is not web app but rather desktop applications. I have no experience with IIS. I thought it is only for web app? Is it possible to write a standalone WCF service without IIS?

Comment: @Kevin, yes, WCF can be self hosted, but I am sure you will find IIS a breeze if you give it a change, hosting in IIS is a nice option.

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks alot I am sure this will solve me problem :)

Answer (score 2):

It's not exactly true, there are couple of almost unknow but powerful tools that you can use free:

- NetFluid: http://www.netfluid.org/
- Service Stack: http://www.servicestack.net